# Two servlets accessing objects loaded by different class loaders, any workaround?

Tags: java, class, serialization, deserialization, classloader

I have two servlets that access and manipulate a list of shared objects, access via a singleton class.  Servlet1 is loaded by ClassLoader1 and Servlet2 is loaded by ClassLoader2.  When I try to cast objects from the common list, I get a ClassCastException.  So I serialize and de-serialize each object before use and that solved the problem.  But I read that serialization/de-serialization have huge performance impact.  So I am wondering if there is a better way to handle this?  Note that I have no control over which classloader the servlets use initially.

The servlets are from a web application (not mine) off a websphere server.  Each time a new servlet is executed, the web application creates a new classloader for it.  Again I have no code level access to this web application.

Comment: What container are you running in?

Comment: share via a local mysql database.

Comment: "I read that serialization/de-serialization have huge performance impact" - it may do, or it may not. Measure it. If it's not significant, then don't worry about it.